# Why am I getting TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable builtin_function_or_method object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and I am starting with python. I am trying to make a method that will take an equation and solve for an unknown variable.
It works for just one equation (one operator) but didn't work when I tried to make it return value based on an operator.

**This worked:**

```
def solveforx(y):
    x, add, num1, equal, num2 = y.split()

    # convert the strings into ints
    num1, num2 = int(num1), int(num2)
    # convert the result into a string and join it to the string "x = "
    return "x = "+ str(num2 - num1)

print(solveforx("X + 5 = 9"))
```

**This didn't:**

```
def solveforx(y):
    x, op, num1, equal, num2 = y.split

    num1, num2 = int(num1), int(num2)

    if op == "+":
        return "x = " + str(num2 - num1)
    elif op == "-":
        return "x = " + str(num1 + num2)
    elif op == "*":
        return "x = " + str(num2/num1)
    elif op == "/":
        return "x = " + str(num1*num2)
    else:
        return "wrong operator"

print(solveforx("X + 5 = 9"))
```

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable builtin_function_or_method object

Comment: `y.split` in the second function isn't instantiated.  You have to add parentheses to the end like this: `y.split()`

Comment: suggestion for future questions.  please include the stack that you get with the exception.

Comment: I guess the question should be removed. It is quite obvious where the exception is raised. And it is quite obvious that `split` method have to be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses after `y.split`, so you tried to unpack the method `split` instead of its actual result.

It should be

```py
x, op, num1, equal, num2 = y.split()
```